# Reflected process - Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I am still new to stochastic processes and I tried to do this exercise. I don't know how to go on.

Define the maximum process
\begin{align*}
M_t = \max_{0 \leqslant s \leqslant t} W_s,
\end{align*}
and hitting times
\begin{align*}
T_a = \inf\{s : W_s = a\}.
\end{align*}
Give an expression for $\mathbb P(T_a \leqslant t)$ in terms of the maximum process $M_t$.

For any fixed $T$ and a standard Brownian motion $W_t$, the reflected process defined by
\begin{align*}
\tilde W_t^T = \begin{cases}
W_t, & t \leqslant T \\
2W_T-W_t, & t > T,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
is itself a standard Brownian motion.

Prove that for any $x \leqslant a$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(M_t \geqslant a, W_t \leqslant x) = \mathbb P(\tilde W_t^{T_a} \geqslant 2a-x) = 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{2a-x}{\sqrt t}\right).
\end{align*}
Using symmetry, conclude that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(T_a \leqslant t) = 2(1 - \Phi(a/\sqrt t)).
\end{align*}
For the first part, we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(T_a \leqslant t) &= \mathbb P(\inf\{s : W_s = a\} \leqslant t)
= \mathbb P\left(\max_{0 \leqslant s \leqslant t} W_s \geqslant a\right) = \mathbb P(M_t \geqslant a).
\end{align*}
Assume that $\tilde W_t^{T_a} \geqslant 2a-x$.

If $t \leqslant T_a$, it is $\tilde W_t^{T_a} = W_t$.

Suppose that $M_t < a$. Then
\begin{align*}
2a-x \leqslant W_t \leqslant \max_{0 \leqslant s \leqslant t} W_s = M_t < a,
\end{align*}
which implies $x > a$. So we must have $M_t \geqslant a$.

But how can I prove in this case, that $W_t \leqslant x$?

If $t > T_a$, we have
\begin{align*}
M_t = \max_{0 \leqslant s \leqslant t} W_s \geqslant \max_{0 \leqslant s \leqslant T_a} W_s \geqslant W_{T_a} = a.
\end{align*}
Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
W_t &= 2W_{T_a} + W_t - 2W_{T_a} = 2a - (2W_{T_a} - W_t) = 2a - \tilde W_t^{T_a} 
\leqslant 2a - (2a-x) = x.
\end{align*}
Conversely, assume that $M_t \geqslant a \geqslant x$ and $W_t \leqslant x \leqslant a$.

If $t \leqslant T_a$, I do not know how to show that $W_t \geqslant 2a-x$.

If $t > T_a$, we get that
\begin{align*}
\tilde W_t^{T_a} &= 2W_{T_a} - W_t  = 2a - W_t \geqslant 2a - x.
\end{align*}

We get the second equality as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(\tilde W_t^{T_a} \geqslant 2a-x) &= 1 - \mathbb P(\tilde W_t^{T_a} \leqslant 2a-x).
\end{align*}
Since $\tilde W_t^{T_a}$ is itself a standard Brownian motion with mean 0 and variance $t$, we get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(\tilde W_t^{T_a} \geqslant 2a-x) = 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{2a-x}{\sqrt t}\right).
\end{align*}
Now, we see that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(T_a \leqslant t) &= \mathbb P(M_t \geqslant a)
= \mathbb P(M_t \geqslant a, W_t \leqslant x) + \mathbb P(M_t \geqslant a, W_t > x) \\
&= 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{2a-x}{\sqrt t}\right) + \mathbb P(M_t \geqslant a, W_t > x)
\end{align*}

Here, I do not see how to obtain $2(1 - \Phi(a/\sqrt t))$.

Comment: I looked at your proof in detail and your mistake is not taking into account that $t$ can not take any values. Specifically, if $\tilde{W}_t^{T_a}\ge 2a-x$ and $t\le T_a$, then on the one hand $W_t\ge 2a-x$ and on the other hand $W_t<a$ which is not possible.

Comment: Similarly, if $M_t\ge a$, then necessarily $T_a\le t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with your first problem. You want to calculate

$$\mathbb P(M_t \geqslant a, W_t \leqslant x).$$

As you noted,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(M_t \geqslant a, W_t \leqslant x)=\mathbb P(T_a \leqslant t, W_t \leqslant x)&=\mathbb P(T_a \leqslant t, W_t -2W_{T_a}\leqslant x-2a)\\
&=\mathbb P(T_a \leqslant t, \tilde{W}_t^{T_a}\geqslant 2a-x),
\end{align*}

where the last line follows because $t\ge T_a$. Lastly,

$$\mathbb P(T_a \leqslant t, \tilde{W}_t^{T_a}\geqslant 2a-x)=\mathbb P(\tilde{W}_t^{T_a}\geqslant 2a-x)-\mathbb P(T_a > t, \tilde{W}_t^{T_a}\geqslant 2a-x),$$

but if $T_a>t$, $\{\tilde{W}_t^{T_a}\ge 2a-x\}=\{W_t\ge 2a-x\}\subset\{W_t\ge a\}\subset\{T_a\le t\}$, which means that $\mathbb P(T_a > t, \tilde{W}_t^{T_a}\geqslant 2a-x)=0$.

For your second question, take $x=a$. The second term will simplify since $\{W_t>a\}\subset\{M_t\ge a\}$.

Note for the first part that we need the reflected Brownian motion to be a Brownian motion for any $T$ hitting time (you wrote for any fixed $T$).

Comment: Hi, can you please take a look at a similar problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126681/max-of-absolute-value-of-a-brownian-motion/3126708?noredirect=1